# TypeError: detectCollisions() takes exactly 8 arguments (9 given)

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, typeerror

i keep getting this type error TypeError: detectCollisions() takes exactly 8 arguments (9 given)

```
def detectCollisions(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2,):

    if (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):

        return True

    elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):

        return True

    elif (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):

        return True

    elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):

        return True

    else:

        return False

def update(self,gravity,blocklist):
    if(self.velocity<0):
        self.falling=True
    blockX,blockY=0,0

    collision=False

    for block in blocklist:

        collision = self.detectCollisions(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height)
```

im not sure what is wrong with it, i have already added a def for detect collision

Comment: Aside: why are you passing self attributes into `self.detectCollisions()`? Shouldn't `detectCollisions()` have access to `self.x`, `self.y`, etc. implicitly?

Comment: Yes, it seems like the method should simply take `self, other`.

Comment: You should show us some codes. It's not enough, where is your `class` ?

Comment: i have added more code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you missed `self` in your method declaration

```
def detectCollisions(x, y, ....
```

The first argument should be `self`, then your custom arguments.

When calling it, the `self` is passed implicitly (so it gets 9 arguments, when you used just 8 in the call)

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical problem learning python. 
The first parameter in a member function is always the "self"-parameter.
It is included in the call "behind the scenes".

That is why it says 9 arguments when you've only given 8. 
Here is a class declaration illustrating this, try play around with the code:

```
class TestClass():
    def test(self, _param1, _param2):
        print("_param1:" + str(_param1) + "_param2:" + _param2)

_instance = TestClass()
_instance.test("a", "b")
_instance.test("a", "b", "c")
```

The first call works, the second doesn't and you get that typical error message. 
This also goes the other way, you always have to add the "self" parameter to the declaration.

Comment: not really sure what you mean could you explain it a bit more.

Comment: A function in a class is often called a member function. A member function in Python has "self" as the first parameter.
It looks like the functions in your code are member functions in a class declaration. If they are, you should change
`def detectCollisions(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2,)` into 
`def detectCollisions(self, x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2)`.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi if its not a class but standalone functions, then we'll have to start over..